# Immediately-invoked function expression, calling variables/ functions outside its scope

Tags: javascript

Suppose following is the IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression)

```
(function (myfunction) {
    myfunction(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function ($, window, document) {
    var dosum = function (a,b) {
        return a+b;
    };

    var substractnum = function (a,b) {
        return a-b;
    };
}));

dosum(); //I want to call dosum() here out of its scope. How can this be achieve.
```

Now I want to call `dosum()` outside of its scope. How can it be achieved?

Comment: So declare it on any outer common scope (global?!)

Comment: Isnt there any other way? That I will do lastly if there is no other solution :)

Comment: You could return function from iife, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/kpa3wk21/ Not sure it is what you are looking for of course

Comment: doing that shows error - TypeError: iife is not a function

Comment: and what if there are more than one functions in the scope and I particularly want to call dosum() ?

Comment: But did you check jsfiddle??? If you want to get more variables, return an object containing them

Comment: okay cool.. seems to be working. Thanks a tons!!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!